# MATLAB bins setting in histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram, bins

I want to change how data are distributed in the histogram that I built.My histogram looks like

[image]

But I want it to look like

[image]

I set

```
bins1=[10,30,50,70];
hist(data,bins1)
```

How can I arrange the bins as in the second figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `histc` instead of `hist`. `histc` allows you to define the edges while `hist` uses the second input parameter as centers.