# create bins based on a range of values for histogram figure

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure

I am doing some analysis and need to produce a histogram plot. I know how to create the standard histogram plot but I need something like the image below, where each point is an interval on the x axis. Each bin is based on a value from x-x for example.

[image: Example histogram]

Comment: @rinkert , agree on dupe but that answer doesn't use [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) which is now recommended over [`histc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) used by that answer.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan, ok retracted my flag, since the other answer is not recommended. Then a new answer using `histc` could be added here or in the other post.

Comment: i am not sure what answer you are both referring to

Comment: @rinkert, Agreed, I think the answer lies in using [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) and adjusting the [histogram properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram-properties.html) but don't have time right now to do full quality answer.

Comment: Related post (but not duplicate) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29016872/8239061) but that answer uses function no longer recommended by Matlab.

Comment: What's wrong with just using the argument 'BinWidth' and set the interval to desired spacing? For the 'greater than' bins for histograms, there's a easy sounding solution on Mathworks [link](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/397573-histogram-greater-than-bin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`histogram`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) function, and then set the `XTick` positions and `XTickLabels` accordingly. See the comments in the code for explanation.

```
% random normally distrubuted data
x = 1*randn(1000,1);
edges = -5:1:5;

% create vector with labels (for XTickLabel ... to ...)
labels = [edges(1:end-1); edges(2:end)];
labels = labels(:);

% plot the histogram
figure();
ax = axes;
h = histogram(x, 'BinEdges', edges, 'Normalization', 'Probability');

ax.XTick = edges + mean(diff(edges)/2);
ax.XTickLabel = sprintf('%.1f to %.1f\n', labels);
ax.XTickLabelRotation = 90;

% set yticks to percentage
ax.YTickLabel = cellfun(@(a) sprintf('%i%%', (str2double(a)*100)), ax.YTickLabel, 'UniformOutput', false);

% text above bars
bin_props = h.BinCounts/numel(x);  % determine probabilities per bin in axis units
bin_centers = ax.XTick(1:end-1);  % get the bin centers

txt_heigts = bin_props + 0.01; % put the text slightly above the bar
txt_labels = split(sprintf('%.1f%% ', bin_props*100), ' ');
txt_labels(end) = [];  % remove last cell, is empty because of split.
text(ax, bin_centers, txt_heigts, txt_labels, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center')

% set ylim to fit all text (otherwise text is outside axes)
ylim([0 .4]);
```

Putting the text at the right location may require some tweaking. Most important is the `'HorizontalAlignment'` option, and the distance to the bars. I also used the `'Normalization'`, `'probability'` option from the `histogram` function, and set the y axis to also show percentages.

I figure you can make the addition below yourself when needed.

[image]

---

When your data can be outside of the defined `binedges`, you can clip your data, and set the `XTickLabels` with less than or greater than signs.

```
% when data can be outside of defined edges
x = 5*randn(1000,1);
xclip = x;
xclip(x >= max(edges)) = max(edges);
xclip(x <= min(edges)) = min(edges);

% plot the histogram
figure();
ax = axes;
h = histogram(xclip, 'BinEdges', edges);

ax.XTick = edges + mean(diff(edges)/2);
ax.XTickLabel = sprintf('%.1f to %.1f\n', labels);
ax.XTickLabelRotation = 90;

% set boundary labels
ax.XTickLabel{1} = sprintf('\\leq %.1f', edges(2));
ax.XTickLabel{end-1} = sprintf('\\geq %.1f', edges(end-1));
```

[image]

---

You can also set the outer edges to `-Inf` and `Inf`, as [user2305193](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2305193/user2305193) pointed out. Since the outer bins are then much wider (because they actually extend to `Inf` on the x axis), which you can correct by setting the axis `xlim`. By the default the `XTickLabels` will display `-Inf to -5.0`, which I personally don't like, so I set them to lesser (and equal) than and greater than signs.

```
step = 1;
edges = -5:step:5;                                  % your defined range
edges_inf = [-Inf edges Inf];                       % for histogram
edges_ext = [edges(1)-step edges];                  % for the xticks

x = 5*randn(1000,1);

% plot the histogram
figure();
ax = axes;
h = histogram(x, 'BinEdges', edges_inf, 'Normalization', 'probability');

labels = [edges_inf(1:end-1); edges_inf(2:end)];
labels = labels(:);

ax.XTick = edges_ext + step/2;
ax.XTickLabel = sprintf('%.1f to %.1f\n', labels);
ax.XTickLabelRotation = 90;

% show all bins with equal width (Inf bins are in fact wider)
xlim([min(edges)-step max(edges)+step])

% set boundary labels
ax.XTickLabel{1} = sprintf('\\leq %.1f', edges(1));
ax.XTickLabel{end-1} = sprintf('\\geq %.1f', edges(end));
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant this is exactly what i needed. Is there anyway to show the percentage like in the original figure i attached. I know how to normalise the axis through normalisation - probability.

Comment: @VBA_Novice, look at the [`normalization`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram-properties.html) property. Choose your normalisation method and use that property when you call the `histogram` function.

Comment: Excellent answer. Answers OP's question & clear for future visitors.  (+1)

Comment: @Hoki i know how to normalize when calling the histogram function. What i was asking: is there anyway to show the percentage on top of each bin, as shown in my picture that i posted.

Comment: i agree this is an excellent response. It has helped me. thank you @rinkert